# Record audio on Android with MediaPlayer as source?

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, microphone

On Android, you can record audio from the microphone using the MediaRecorder class:
MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

I want to record some parts of audio being played by a MediaPlayer instance instead (or some other audio playback device). Is that possible? How would I set a custom audio source?

To summarize; **how do I stream audio into the MediaRecorder from an arbitrary audio source?**

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't really. Not on a stock Android device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Will try to find another solution to my problem :)

Comment: You're asking how to capture audio that the device is currently playing without connecting an audio patch cord from the output to the input, right?

Comment: Hi,the above post is regarding how to capture audio that the device is currently playing? Please help me if u know how to save the output or capture  of currently playing audio..(I now how to do it from mic but is create lot problem..if u know any other way help mee...Thanks in Advance )

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an API for that for now. Though it IS possible, you would have to have access to the device's buffer, down to the kernel/hardware level. Even if you find a way, I don't think Android would give you permission to do this on application level.

Comment: Would this require a rooted device? Or would it be possible to do this using the NDK?

Comment: Yes. Though I can't tell you 100% sure, it is the most probable solution. A rooted device and native development (C++ I guess) as you'll be dealing with hardware/kernel... I myself had this same idea, but it would get too complicated, and most people wouldn't benefit from it.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yeah. I hate this comment restriction on Stack Overflow. I can't comment, so I'm posting things as answers. And why not? Nobody else has posted a solution, and we all know there's no feasible solution for this.