# Play an audio file as soon as Text To Speech is completed in Android

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

I'm trying to develop an Android app where as soon as the text to speech is completed an audio file has to be played. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and that is in the method `onUtteranceCompletedListener()` we can know whether the speech is stopped or not and then we can write the code to play the audio file

Comment: When you are asking a question and you get answer by own, you should add some details also.

Comment: this is the solution to my problem which i found it few days back but couldnt find time to tell here. I have told the methods which we have to use. More than this means I have to include my code here which I can't do

Comment: First of all I am not asking to put your code here and because of this question could be helpful for another user, simply you can put some links which you followed or may help in brief.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't get wrong idea, you want to use text-to-speech to read some text and store the speech audio into phone in the meantime? And play the audio later?

Have you checked [AudioRecordTest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)? You can record audio and then play it later. Worth to try but I don't think you can get a good quality from the microphone. Hope this helps:)

By the way, as far as I know, android only support to record from mic for **unrooted** phone, which you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html). Let me know if you can record sound source from the android system.

Comment: it should not get recorded from mic

Comment: @Rosalie I searched around but can not find a solution for unrooted phone, this link also discussed about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849834/record-audio-on-android-with-mediaplayer-as-source Good luck.

Comment: its not about recording. I have the audio file and it has to be played as soon as the text to speech completes.

Comment: This helps? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener)