# Is there any way to using audio file for source of MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

now I'm recording video using MediaRecorder, source from surface.

And want to record audio too!

```
MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

mRecorder.setInputSurface(surface);
```

but I can't find **setAudioSource** using target for file or stream. (also see [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html)) (not MIC, CAMCORDER, ... etc)

how I can implement the feature? or which keywords should I search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After clarification** 
I do not think there is such an API at the moment.

**Before clarification**

Check if you have the correct import:

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
```

`setAudioSource` is available since API level 1. 
Check the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) for more information. It has a sample you could refer to. 
If the above is not working , try to clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: sorry for confuse question.

I want to looking for setAudioSource for audio file, not MIC, HEADPHONES... etc

Comment: @Maybe
Oh I get it now. Are you asking the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849834/record-audio-on-android-with-mediaplayer-as-source

Comment: thank you, and then how i can save video from audio source, please recommend :p